# VBA output into Excel cell

Tags: excel, vba, url

I'm constructing a worksheet and trying to output the airport's TAF (forecast) into cell B7 in Excel.  The debugger keeps flagging the request.Open line with the error message "The URL does not use a recognized protocol".  Any advice would be most welcome.

```
Sub InitializeTAF()
    Dim url As String
    Dim request As New WinHttpRequest
    Dim response As String
    Dim ids As String
    Dim format As String
    
    ' Set the TAF data request parameters
    ids = "RKSO"
    format = "raw"
    
    ' Construct the request URL
    url = "https://www.aviationweather.gov/taf/data?ids=RKSO&format=raw&date=&submit=Get+TAF+data" & format & "&stationString=" & ids
    
    ' Send the request and get the response data
    request.Open "GET", url = "https://www.aviationweather.gov/taf/data?ids=RKSO&format=raw&date=&submit=Get+TAF+data", False
    request.Send
    response = request.ResponseText
    
    ' Update the TAF display with the new data
    ActiveSheet.Range("B7").Value = response
    
    ' Refresh the TAF display every 2 minutes
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:02:00"), "InitializeTAF"
End Sub
```

I've tried using url = http:// on the request.open line and it still gave me the same error.  The expected result for the macro as mentioned earlier is to output the lines of the TAF into cell B7 on my active worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ok, just modify one line:

```
Sub InitializeTAF()
    Dim url As String
    Dim request As New WinHttpRequest
    Dim response As String
    Dim ids As String
    Dim format As String
    
    ' Set the TAF data request parameters
    ids = "RKSO"
    format = "raw"
    
    ' Construct the request URL
    url = "https://www.aviationweather.gov/taf/data?ids=RKSO&format=raw&date=&submit=Get+TAF+data" & format & "&stationString=" & ids
    
    ' Send the request and get the response data
    request.Open "GET", url, False
    request.Send
    response = request.ResponseText
    
    ' Update the TAF display with the new data
    ActiveSheet.Range("B7").Value = response
    
    ' Refresh the TAF display every 2 minutes
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:02:00"), "InitializeTAF"
End Sub
```

Since the code is running continuously every 2 minutes, it would be good to pass a worksheet as parameter instead of using ActiveSheet

```
Sub InitializeTAF(ws as Worksheet)
   ....
   ws.Range("B7").Value = response
   ....
End Sub
```